# Linear layout inside Frame Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have the following code in Android Studio in which I have two Linear Layouts inside a Frame layout. However, the buttons in both layout map on top of each other. Is it possible to have the two linear layouts (including the buttons) placed next to each other vertically rather than being mapped on top of peach other?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap.MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fram_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/locate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Locate"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Free Draw" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/config"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Config"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The following is a screenshot of how the buttons appears. [image: Snap]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it appears? Have you tried Relative Layout?

Comment: Why you don't try to use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` in the root of xml code .

And set `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fram_map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/locate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Locate" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Free Draw" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/config"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:text="Config" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:text="Upload" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Stop" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`FrameLayout` will layout all children in the same frame on screen.

If you want multiple children to stack vertically or horizontally, you can wrap them in a `LinearLayout` instead. In this case, you can simply replace that root `FrameLayout` with a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` to stack the two `LinearLayout`s vertically.